# usar aggregate en base a dos columnas del data frame

Tags: r

tengo una matriz de datos (dfA) con varias columnas: provincia (dfA es un subset para una de las provincias), municipio, cultivo, número de explotaciones, superficie, producción... Y quiero calcular el número de explotaciones totales, superficie total, producción total... para cada cultivo de cada municipio.

ESTRUCTURA de la matriz de datos:

```
    str(dfA)

'data.frame':   523 obs. of  8 variables:

$ CODPROV: Factor w/ 8 levels "4","11","14",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

$ MUN_INE: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...

$ OTE_NUM: Factor w/ 4 levels "15","20","36",..: 1 3 3 3 2 2 2 4 3 3 ...

$ NUM_EXP: num  1 1 7 14 2 2 3 20 3 8 ...

$ PRODEST: num  3510 830 1924 3388 696 ...

$ UTA_TOT: num  1 90 1705 2053 2613 ...

$ SUP_TOT: num  1395 15 820 1846 2519 ...

 $ SAU_TOT: num  1368 15 367 1779 2450 ...
```

PRIMERAS LÍNEAS de la matriz de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CÓDIGO que llevo escrito hasta el momento:

```
aggregate (cbind(df$NUM_EXP,df$PRODEST,df$UTA_TOT,df$SAU_TOT) ~ df$OTE_NUM, data=dfA, FUN=sum)
```

Sin embargo NO quiero agregar sólo según `'df$OTE_NUM'` sino según `'df$MUN_INE'` y `'df$OTE_NUM'`. Para ello he intentado crear una lista:

```
aggregate (cbind(df$NUM_EXP,df$PRODEST,df$UTA_TOT,df$SAU_TOT) ~ list(df$MUN_INE, df$OTE_NUM), data=dfA, FUN=sum)
```

Pero introducciendo la lista me da un error ¿cómo puedo hacerlo? Necesito algo así: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

MUCHAS GRACIAS por la ayuda : )

Comment: ¡Buenas! Ya he conseguido solucionarlo, lo he hecho de esta manera: dfA.sum<-aggregate (cbind(dfA$NUM_EXP,dfA$PRODEST,dfA$UTA_TOT,dfA$SAU_TOT) ~ dfA$MUN_INE + dfA$OTE_NUM, data=dfA, FUN=sum)

Comment: Que bien! Le recomiendo usar el paquete [`dplyr`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) que tiene funciones más literales y que facilitan el uso de trabajo con data frames (agrupar, ordenar, seleccionar, filtrar) no es NADA que no tenga el R por si solo, pero tiene muchas más ventajas además de que es lo que está de moda (y para quedarse).

Comment: @LauraPradera Sería deseable que publicaras la solución que encontraste como una respuesta a tu pregunta. De este modo, otras personas con el mismo problema podrán usar esta pregunta como referencia.

Answer (score 3):

¡Buenas! Ya he conseguido solucionarlo, lo he hecho de esta manera:

```
dfA.sum<-aggregate (cbind(dfA$NUM_EXP,dfA$PRODEST,dfA$UTA_TOT,dfA$SAU_TOT) ~ dfA$MUN_INE + dfA$OTE_NUM, data=dfA, FUN=sum)
```

<sub>Gracias toledano, jbkunst y Juan Bosco.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Como propuso [@jbkunst](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/9323/jbkunst), usando el paquete `dplyr` es más sencillo y más fácil es también interpretar el código.

Aquí intento reproducir algunas líneas de tu `dataframe`.

```
library(dplyr)

(dfA <- data_frame(CODPROV = c( 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3),
                   OTE_NUM = c(15, 36, 36, 20, 20, 20, 36, 36, 20, 36, 36, 36),
                   NUM_EXP = c( 1,  1,  7, 14,  2,  3,  3,  8, 45,  6,  1,  4)))

# A tibble: 12 × 3
   CODPROV OTE_NUM NUM_EXP
     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1        1      15       1
2        1      36       1
3        1      36       7
4        1      20      14
5        1      20       2
6        1      20       3
7        2      36       3
8        2      36       8
9        2      20      45
10       3      36       6
11       3      36       1
12       3      36       4
```

Ahora agrupo según `CODPROV` y `OTE_NUM` con `group_by`, y calculo la suma de `NUM_EXP` y la llamo `SUM_NUM_EXP` con la función `summarise`.

```
dfA %>% 
  group_by(CODPROV, OTE_NUM) %>%
  summarise(SUM_NUM_EXP = sum(NUM_EXP))

  CODPROV OTE_NUM SUM_NUM_EXP
    <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>
1       1      15           1
2       1      20          19
3       1      36           8
4       2      20          45
5       2      36          11
6       3      36          11
```