# calcular proporción por cultivo y municipio

Tags: r

si tengo un dataframe donde una columna es el municipio, otra los cultivos más frecuentes para cada municipio, otra más que es la superficie de cada cultivo y quiero hacer una proporción de la superficie a nivel municipal ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? ¿Es necesario un bucle o puede hacerse mediante las funciones de R?

Ejemplo:

Si tengo estos datos:

```
Municipio, Cultivo, Superficie;
    1,        15,       23;
    1,        22,       45;
    1,        31,       69;
    2,        22,       15;
    2,        40,       65;
    4,        15,       23;
    4,        22,       37;
    4,        31,       21;
    4,        40,       85;
        ...
```

Lo que busco es:

```
Municipio, Cultivo, Superficie_proporcion;
     1,      15,        23/(23+45+69);
     1,      22,        45/(23+45+69);
     1,      31,        69/(23+45+69);
     2,      22,        15/(15+65);
     2,      40,        65/(15+65);
     4,      15,        23/(23+37+21+85);
     4,      22,        37/(23+37+21+85);
     4,      31,        21/(23+37+21+85);
     4,      40,        85/(23+37+21+85);
```

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Siempre es recomendable que coloques lo que has intentado hacer. A nadie le gusta ayudar a quien no muestra esfuerzo ;).

Answer (score 2):

Continuando con la recomendación que [realicé ayer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52752/usar-aggregate-en-base-a-dos-columnas-del-data-frame). Lo mejor es usar `dplyr`:

```r
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
df <- read_delim("Municipio,Cultivo,Superficie
1,15,23
1,22,45
1,31,69
2,22,15
2,40,65
4,15,23
4,22,37
4,31,21
4,40,85", 
  delim = ",")

glimpse(df)
#> Observations: 9
#> Variables: 3
#> $ Municipio  <int> 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4
#> $ Cultivo    <int> 15, 22, 31, 22, 40, 15, 22, 31, 40
#> $ Superficie <int> 23, 45, 69, 15, 65, 23, 37, 21, 85

df %>% # agrupamos por Municipo
   group_by(Municipio) %>% # mutate para crear variable
   mutate(Superficie_proporcion = Superficie/sum(Superficie))

#> Source: local data frame [9 x 4]
#> Groups: Municipio [3]
#> 
#>   Municipio Cultivo Superficie Superficie_proporcion
#>       <int>   <int>      <int>                 <dbl>
#> 1         1      15         23             0.1678832
#> 2         1      22         45             0.3284672
#> 3         1      31         69             0.5036496
#> 4         2      22         15             0.1875000
#> 5         2      40         65             0.8125000
#> 6         4      15         23             0.1385542
#> 7         4      22         37             0.2228916
#> 8         4      31         21             0.1265060
#> 9         4      40         85             0.5120482
```

Comment: Muchas gracias jbkunst, sí, estudié el enlace sobre dplyr, pero estaba enfrascada en la idea de hacer un bucle y dentro introducir un subset y un aggregate o un apply... pero no conseguía solucionarlo, y tú lo has hecho en un par de líneas. Gracias.

Comment: ;)! Sí, es difícil salir de lo que uno conoce, por eso hay que seguir aprendiendo siempre! De nada.

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa usando las funciones `base` de R. Asumimos que df es el nombre de tu tabla.

```
df$Proporcion <- unlist(lapply(split(df, df$Municipio), function(cada_municipio){
      cada_municipio$Superficie / sum(cada_municipio$Superficie)
    }))
```

Lo que hacemos es:

- `split` para dividir df, por Municipio, en una lista de data frames. Cada data frame incluirá únicamente los dates de un sólo "Municipio".
- `lapply` para aplicar una **función anónima** a cada elemento de la lista que creamos con `split`. En este caso, la función es dividir cada valor de "Superficie" por la suma (`sum`) de todos los valores de "Superficie".
- `unlist` para convertir al resultado de `lapply` en un vector. `lapply` siempre devuelve como resultado una lista, pero necesitamos un vector para poder anexar nuestro resultado a nuestro data frame original.
- Asignamos el resultado a una nueva columna de df llamada "Proporción"

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan Bosco, y también gracias por la explicación, no sólo me has ayudado a comprender el código sino a aprender nuevas posibilidades sobre combinación de funciones. Gracias.